# Handle dependent Java library adding new classes?

Tags: java, oop, classpath

My application has the following architecture:

I have a variable amount of classes implementing a specific interface in a library. (These classes all implement the exact same interface).

These are all instantiated by a method, placed in a list, and sent off to some function that processes them in some way.

```
public class Initialize {

    public static void main(String[] args){

         ClassInterface num1 = new ClassA();
         ClassInterface num2 = new ClassB();
         ...
         ClassInterface numX = new ClassX();

         List<ClassInterface> list = new ArrayList<ClassInterface>();
         list.add(num1, num2, num3.....);

         processList(list);
    }

}
```

The above classes (`ClassA`, `ClassB`, etc..) are loaded from a library.

Now, while this works, it is incredibly messy and any time a new class implementing `ClassInterface` is created in the library it requires recompiling the above program (even though nothing has really changed).

Is there a better approach to this kind of problem? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library to scan all classes implementing `ClassInterface` from class path.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");
Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(ClassInterface.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a combination of [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and [`AutoService`](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service), so you can just write `ServiceLoader.load(ClassInterface.class)` and get an `Iterable<ClassInterface>`.